# entry point of a hangfire RecurringJob in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

There is a method on service layer, we need to call it periodically with HangFire, so, the question is, where is the best place to implement a `RecurringJob` in asp.net core?

If [configure method](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/878) in startup.cs is the best, how we can handle all dependencies that method needed in the startup.cs?

I tried this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("FixOrderJob", () => Job.FromExpression<IOrderFixerService>(x => x.FixUnknownOrder()), Cron.MinuteInterval(5));
```

but following error occured:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Anonymous functions, delegates and lambda expressions aren't supported in job method parameters: it's very hard to serialize them and all their scope in general.'
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? `Configure` is called after the IoC/DI container is built, so resolving **is available**. However, the scope of the services vary, when you resolve it form the application container, the services effectively become singletons (in newer ASP.NET Core versions it should throw an exception when you try to resolve an scoped service from application service provider). You would have to resolve dependencies on a per job invocation basis (dunno if/how that can be done in Hangfire didnt used it). But the error message above is unrelated to your question of dependencies

Answer (score 9):

If you want run a recurring job with hangfire, on of the best place to start it, is in startup class.

Based on hagnfire [recurrent task documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html#manipulating-recurring-jobs), The `RecurringJob` class is a facade for the `RecurringJobManager` class. so just inject IRecurringJobManager as argument and configure your jobs there:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IRecurringJobManager recurringJobs)
   {
       //Access To HangFire dashboard : http://app_hostname/hangfire
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        app.UseHangfireServer();
       //....
       //....
       app.UseMvc(); 
       //....
       //....
       recurringJobs.AddOrUpdate("FixOrderJob", Job.FromExpression<IOrderFixerService>(x => x.FixLatestUnknownOrder()), Cron.MinuteInterval(1));
    }
```